# Looking to make my ggplot different colors?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

```
Teeth <- caries$after - caries$before
anova <- aov(Teeth~inst * treat, data=caries)
summary(anova)

ggplot(data = caries, aes(x=inst, y=Teeth, group=inst)) + 
       geom_boxplot(colour = "black", fill = "dodgerblue")
```

This is my code so far - caries is the imported data set.

I am trying to make the three different boxes different colors, and right now they are only in dodger blue.

Data

```
caries <- structure(list(subject = 1:69, inst = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
    before = c(7L, 20L, 21L, 1L, 3L, 20L, 9L, 2L, 11L, 15L, 7L, 
    17L, 9L, 1L, 3L, 10L, 13L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 15L, 6L, 4L, 18L, 
    11L, 9L, 4L, 5L, 11L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 8L, 2L, 13L, 
    9L, 15L, 13L, 2L, 9L, 4L, 10L, 7L, 14L, 7L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 19L, 
    10L, 10L, 7L, 13L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 14L, 8L, 3L, 11L, 
    16L, 8L, 0L, 3L), after = c(11L, 24L, 25L, 2L, 7L, 23L, 13L, 
    4L, 13L, 18L, 10L, 17L, 11L, 5L, 7L, 14L, 17L, 4L, 7L, 9L, 
    18L, 8L, 6L, 19L, 12L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 14L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 
    1L, 8L, 4L, 18L, 12L, 18L, 17L, 5L, 12L, 6L, 14L, 11L, 15L, 
    10L, 6L, 12L, 10L, 19L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 12L, 8L, 3L, 9L, 5L, 
    7L, 14L, 10L, 5L, 12L, 18L, 8L, 1L, 4L), treat = structure(c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("APF", "SF", 
    "W"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("subject", "inst", "before", 
"after", "treat"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -69L
))
```

https://pastebin.com/MeRw69ky <

Comment: To make a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you either need to provide your data (e.g., using `dput`) or provide an example using a publicly available data set.

Comment: Hello! thank you! I am new on the site and this is my first post, I am trying to figure out how to use dput

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please have a look through the site orientation and help sections.  Also, please have a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/). There is a general expectation on this site that before posting a question, you should do a reasonable amount of research of your own. There are so many resource to answer your question that a simple google search for 'color in ggplot' would probably be enough.

Comment: Hi!  thank you for these resources. I've tried 5 variations of code and keep getting an error

Comment: ggplot(data = caries, aes(x=inst, y=Teeth, group=inst)) + geom_boxplot(bp + scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "dodgerblue", "green"))
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"ggplot(data = caries, aes(x=inst, y=Teeth, group=inst)) + geom_boxplot(scale_fill_manual(values=c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9"))
ggplot"
> bp + scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("2", "1", "0.5"), 
+ values=c("red", "blue", "green"))
Error: object 'bp' not found
> ggplot(data = caries, aes(x=inst, y=Teeth, fill=inst)) + geom_boxplot(scale_fill_hue(l=40, c=35))
Error: Mapping must be created by `aes()` or `aes_()`

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a variable determine the colors in your plot, you have to map that variable to color in an `aes` call. Here's an example with the `mpg` dataset. I'd suggest reading through the [`ggplot2` docs](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/), because there are a ton of examples there, including at least one that's basically the same as this one.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(x = class, y = hwy, color = class)) +
    geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Created on 2018-04-22 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: https://pastebin.com/MeRw69ky

I have tried to paste the CSV here, unsure if it will work

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it with this code. thanks everybody for your help!

```
ggplot(caries, aes(inst, Teeth, group=inst, fill = inst)) + geom_boxplot()

ggplot(caries, aes(treat, Teeth, group=treat, fill = treat)) + geom_boxplot()
```